# How to acces one .phtml file in another .phtml file magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4

In magento development how to access one ".phtml" file in one or more other ".phtml" files?
i accessed my extension " .phtml" file in one page checkout page extension file is working fine but checkout page checkbox click is not working.

Comment: when i am clicking on register or as guest checkbox it is not working after access extension " .phtml" file. i think it is some javascript effect anyone can help me.

Comment: Please follow : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691546/want-to-call-one-phtml-file-in-another-phtml-file-using-anchor-tag

Comment: @Sarvesh you got your solution ?

Comment: @hitesh sorry i did not find solution